# Force Close when waiting for internet response

Tags: java, php, android, httpresponse

My app executed a HTTP Request where it submits data to a php script and then waits for a response. When the phone has an internet connection, but the connection is really bad (i.e. bad signal, or router is not connected to internet) the app simply force closes. How can I stop this?

So far these are the steps it takes

1. Person presses submit button
2. This starts an Async task which makes sure the phone has a connection (bad connections pass this)
3. It executes the HTTP Post
4. It waits for the response

All these steps are surrounded with try and catch which handle exceptions however I'm still getting force closes.

Here is the AsyncTask code

```
private class checkDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Starting the progress dialog
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "",
                "Connecting. Please wait...", true);

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... info) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {

            String us = info[0];
            String ps = info[1];

            String responseText;

            if (us.equals("") || ps.equals("")) {
                //No username or password
                return false;
            } else {
                try {
                    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://www.myfirstagent.com/android/loginquery.php");

                    // Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                            2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                            us));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                            ps));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response;
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response
                                .getEntity());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //problem connecting
                        return false;

                    }

                    if (responseText.equals("accept")) {
                        return true;
                    } else if (responseText.equals("decline")) {
                        //invalid username or password
                        return false;

                    } else {
                        //something went wrong
                        return false;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    //something went wrong
                    return false;
                }
            }

        } else {
            //No connection
            return false;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        // Dismissing the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception that causes the force close ?

Comment: Does you app have the permission to access the internet ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exception is, because it happens in places with no connection, and I am not sure how to simulate a bad connection, as I only have a good connection at my house.

Comment: You could turn on the flight mode at your device...

Comment: If I do this, it does not bypass the connection check. If I have a bad signal, it notices there is a connection, and carries out the request however it then force closes.

Comment: It is performed in the AsyncTask, yes. Also, I have just had a look, I apologise as I didn't know how to do that!

Comment: check first if Internet is avail or not, by Network info

Comment: @TomRichardson awesome! and I guess something is happening outside the Async task.. try figuring out which piece of code is related to it and post it here. also edit your question and add the logCat output it might be helpful.. we just dont have enough information to help you.

Comment: @hotveryspicy It already does this, however, if they have a connection (even if it is a very poor one) it passes this.

Comment: @Joe Its difficult to get the logCat output as I always have a good connection at home. I test for this error when I am out and about and know I have a bad connection. I will do my best to get this for you

Comment: could you post the code of the asynctask where the connexion is made?

Comment: may be deactivating your network check and setting the airplane mode can help you reproduce the problem

Comment: @TomRichardson your AsyncTask seems ok I think.. did you checked that it doesn't crash when it returns false?

Comment: @Joe Yes I have, all those cases seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if response if null.

If you want to catch everything than can happen, you could catch a Throwable.

Learn how to read a stack trace, that's the best advice to give to you. You have to understand where your program fails and how they to get a chance to understand why they fail and correct them.

Comment: I can do this, however I cannot get any error messages as I cannot recreate this error at home with full connection.

Comment: I have done this, however it is not getting the same errors. Even when I remove the check for connection.